# Is there an instruction limit or total size limit for the instructions array for versioned transactions?

Tags: web3.js

Trying to compile instructions into a versioned transaction and getting a rangeError [encoding overruns Uint8Array] for more than 6 transactions. Does anyone know if there's a limit to the buffer length? I see 2048 in the web3.js code but not sure if that is applicable here

Comment: I am having this exact same issue, however the entire point of versioned transactions is to allow for transactions that are larger than the legacy transaction size of 1232 bytes. There has to be some issue here, otherwise what is the point of versioned transactions?

Comment: have you used address lookup table that should help you in reducing the Size

Answer (score 4):

The transaction limit is 1232 bytes, so if your serialized transaction is bigger than that, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. range is >=0 and <=1231. Mine was 1232 and was not accepted. the problem was I was closing token accounts and at the same time i was extending the look up table:

```
// Adding addresses to a lookup table is known as "extending"
    const message: VersionedMessage = new TransactionMessage({
      instructions:[closeInstructions,extendTransactions],
      payerKey: myKeypair.publicKey,
      recentBlockhash,
    }).compileToV0Message([lookUpTable]);
```

The problem was after I extended the look up table I had to wait 1 second

```
function sleep(s: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, s * 1000));
}
```

Before creating the closeInstructions I had to call `sleep(1)`